# Children's route disable the root's route in angular navbar angular 15

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

my problem is when I add the route of childrens (./contact/...) to the contact config module they disable the root route but when I comment them it works normally

A friend said it was a problem of permission and I was going to make it as a split dropdown but when he said that I search for it but I couldn't find the problem

contact-config.module.ts

```
`    `import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CONTACT_ROUTE_PROVIDERS } from './providers/route.provider';
import { CONTACT_INFOS_CONTACT_INFO_ROUTE_PROVIDER } from './providers/contact-info-route.provider';
import { PERSONALS_PERSONAL_ROUTE_PROVIDER } from './providers/personal-route.provider';
import { ORGANIZATIONS_ORGANIZATION_ROUTE_PROVIDER } from './providers/organization-route.provider';
import { ADDRESSES_ADDRESS_ROUTE_PROVIDER } from './providers/address-route.provider';
import { NATURE_TYPES_NATURE_TYPE_ROUTE_PROVIDER } from './providers/nature-type-route.provider';
import { CONTACT_NATURES_CONTACT_NATURE_ROUTE_PROVIDER } from './providers/contact-nature-route.provider';
import { EXPERIENCE_TYPES_EXPERIENCE_TYPE_ROUTE_PROVIDER } from './providers/experience-type-route.provider';
import { EXPERTS_EXPERT_ROUTE_PROVIDER } from './providers/expert-route.provider';
import { ORGANIZATION_STAKEHOLDERS_ORGANIZATION_STAKEHOLDER_ROUTE_PROVIDER } from './providers/organization-stakeholder-route.provider';
import { NATURE_TYPES_NATURE_TYPE_TRANSLATION_ROUTE_PROVIDER } from './providers/nature-type-translation-route.provider';
import { CONTACT_INFOS_CONTACT_INFO_TRANSLATION_ROUTE_PROVIDER } from './providers/contact-info-translation-route.provider';
import { EXPERIENCE_TYPES_EXPERIENCE_TYPE_TRANSLATION_ROUTE_PROVIDER } from './providers/experience-type-translation-route.provider';

@NgModule()
export class ContactConfigModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<ContactConfigModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: ContactConfigModule,
      providers: [
        CONTACT_ROUTE_PROVIDERS,
        CONTACT_INFOS_CONTACT_INFO_ROUTE_PROVIDER,
        PERSONALS_PERSONAL_ROUTE_PROVIDER,
        ORGANIZATIONS_ORGANIZATION_ROUTE_PROVIDER,
        ADDRESSES_ADDRESS_ROUTE_PROVIDER,
        NATURE_TYPES_NATURE_TYPE_ROUTE_PROVIDER,
        CONTACT_NATURES_CONTACT_NATURE_ROUTE_PROVIDER,
        EXPERIENCE_TYPES_EXPERIENCE_TYPE_ROUTE_PROVIDER,
        EXPERTS_EXPERT_ROUTE_PROVIDER,
        ORGANIZATION_STAKEHOLDERS_ORGANIZATION_STAKEHOLDER_ROUTE_PROVIDER,
        NATURE_TYPES_NATURE_TYPE_TRANSLATION_ROUTE_PROVIDER,
        CONTACT_INFOS_CONTACT_INFO_TRANSLATION_ROUTE_PROVIDER,
        EXPERIENCE_TYPES_EXPERIENCE_TYPE_TRANSLATION_ROUTE_PROVIDER,
      ],
    };
  }
}`    
`
```

route.provider.ts (Root)

```
    import { eLayoutType, RoutesService } from '@abp/ng.core';
import { APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { eContactRouteNames } from '../enums/route-names';

export const CONTACT_ROUTE_PROVIDERS = [
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: configureRoutes,
    deps: [RoutesService],
    multi: true,
  },
];

export function configureRoutes(routes: RoutesService) {
  return () => {
    routes.add([
      {
        path: '/contact',
        name: eContactRouteNames.Contact,
        iconClass: 'fas fa-book',
        layout: eLayoutType.application,
        order: 3,
        requiredPolicy:'Contact.ContactInfos'
  
      },
    ]);
  };
}
```

contact-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ContactComponent } from './components/contact.component';
import { loadContactInfoModuleAsChild } from './contact-infos/contact-info/contact-info.module';
import { loadPersonalModuleAsChild } from './personals/personal/personal.module';
import { loadOrganizationModuleAsChild } from './organizations/organization/organization.module';
import { loadAddressModuleAsChild } from './addresses/address/address.module';
import { loadNatureTypeModuleAsChild } from './nature-types/nature-type/nature-type.module';
import { loadContactNatureModuleAsChild } from './contact-natures/contact-nature/contact-nature.module';
import { loadExperienceTypeModuleAsChild } from './experience-types/experience-type/experience-type.module';
import { loadExpertModuleAsChild } from './experts/expert/expert.module';
import { loadOrganizationStakeholderModuleAsChild } from './organization-stakeholders/organization-stakeholder/organization-stakeholder.module';
import { loadNatureTypeTranslationModuleAsChild } from './nature-types/nature-type-translation/nature-type-translation.module';
import { loadContactInfoTranslationModuleAsChild } from './contact-infos/contact-info-translation/contact-info-translation.module';
import { loadExperienceTypeTranslationModuleAsChild } from './experience-types/experience-type-translation/experience-type-translation.module';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
     pathMatch: 'full',
    component: ContactComponent,
  },
  { path: 'contact-infos', loadChildren: loadContactInfoModuleAsChild },
  { path: 'personals', loadChildren: loadPersonalModuleAsChild },
  { path: 'organizations', loadChildren: loadOrganizationModuleAsChild },
  { path: 'addresses', loadChildren: loadAddressModuleAsChild },
  { path: 'nature-types', loadChildren: loadNatureTypeModuleAsChild },
  { path: 'contact-natures', loadChildren: loadContactNatureModuleAsChild },
  { path: 'experience-types', loadChildren: loadExperienceTypeModuleAsChild },
  { path: 'experts', loadChildren: loadExpertModuleAsChild },
  { path: 'organization-stakeholders', loadChildren: loadOrganizationStakeholderModuleAsChild },
  { path: 'nature-type-translations', loadChildren: loadNatureTypeTranslationModuleAsChild },
  { path: 'contact-info-translations', loadChildren: loadContactInfoTranslationModuleAsChild },
  {
    path: 'experience-type-translations',
    loadChildren: loadExperienceTypeTranslationModuleAsChild,
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class ContactRoutingModule {}
```

contact.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, NgModuleFactory, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CoreModule, LazyModuleFactory } from '@abp/ng.core';
import { ThemeSharedModule } from '@abp/ng.theme.shared';
import { ContactComponent } from './components/contact.component';
import { ContactRoutingModule } from './contact-routing.module';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ChartModule } from '@abp/ng.components/chart.js';
import { CommercialUiModule } from '@volo/abp.commercial.ng.ui';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ContactComponent],
  imports: [CoreModule, ThemeSharedModule, ContactRoutingModule,ReactiveFormsModule,ChartModule,CommercialUiModule],
  exports: [ContactComponent],
})
export class ContactModule {
  static forChild(): ModuleWithProviders<ContactModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: ContactModule,
      providers: [],
    };
  }

  static forLazy(): NgModuleFactory<ContactModule> {
    return new LazyModuleFactory(ContactModule.forChild());
  }
}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { AuthGuard, PermissionGuard } from '@abp/ng.core';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  // {
  //   path: '',
  //   pathMatch: 'full',
  //   loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule),
  // }, 

  // { path: 'my-dashboard', component: MyDashBoardComponent },

   {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    loadChildren: () => import('./myhome/myhome.module').then(m => m.MyHomeModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: () => import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard, PermissionGuard],
  },
  {
    path: 'contact',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('../../projects/contact/src/lib/contact.module').then(m => m.ContactModule.forLazy()),
  }, 
  {
    path: 'account',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('../../projects/account/public/src/account-public.module').then(m => m.AccountPublicModule.forLazy()),
  },    
   {
    path: 'file-management',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('../../projects/file-management/src/lib/file-management.module').then(m => m.FileManagementModule.forLazy()),
  },
  {
    path: 'gdpr',
    loadChildren: () => import('@volo/abp.ng.gdpr').then(m => m.GdprModule.forLazy()),
  },
 
  {
    path: 'identity',
    loadChildren: () => import('../../projects/identity/src/lib/identity.module').then(m => m.IdentityModule.forLazy()),
  },

   {
    path: 'language-management',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('../../projects/language-management/src/lib/language-management.module').then(m => m.LanguageManagementModule.forLazy()),
  },
   {
    path: 'saas',
    loadChildren: () => import('../../projects/saas/src/lib/saas.module').then(m => m.SaasModule.forLazy()),
  },

  {
    path: 'audit-logs',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('../../projects/audit-logging/src/lib/audit-logging.module').then(m => m.AuditLoggingModule.forLazy()),
  },

   {
    path: 'openiddict',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('../../projects/openiddictpro/src/lib/openiddictpro.module').then(m => m.OpeniddictproModule.forLazy()),
  },
  {
    path: 'text-template-management',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('@volo/abp.ng.text-template-management').then(m =>
        m.TextTemplateManagementModule.forLazy()
      ),
  },
  {
    path: 'setting-management',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('@abp/ng.setting-management').then(m => m.SettingManagementModule.forLazy()),
  },
  {
    path: 'core',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('../../projects/core/src/lib/core.module').then(m => m.CorModule.forLazy()),
  }, 
  {
    path: 'power-of-attorneys',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('../../projects/power-of-attorneys/src/lib/power-of-attorneys.module').then(m => m.PowerOfAttorneysModule.forLazy()),
  },
  {
    path: 'litigations',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('../../projects/litigations/src/lib/litigations.module').then(m => m.LitigationsModule.forLazy()),
  },
  
  {
    path: 'administrative-works',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('../../projects/administrative-works/src/lib/administrative-works.module').then(m => m.AdministrativeWorksModule.forLazy()),
  },
  {
    path: 'gdpr-cookie-consent',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./gdpr-cookie-consent/gdpr-cookie-consent.module').then(
        m => m.GdprCookieConsentModule
      ),
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {})],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).